# Importing more than 1 glue catalog tables into a redshift table

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, aws-glue

I have more than 1 file in S3 which I would like to import into Redshift. The command line for copying is giving me incomprehensible errors. So I went and used AWS Glue crawler to get the files into my Glue catalog. I then created a connection for Redshift. I used a Glue Job to ingest the data into Redshift.

I was able to get the data from a file clicks_001.json in S3 into a Redshift table clicks. That worked. But the problem is I have 1000s of such files and I want to get all of them into the same Redshift table.

I tried passing in parameters to the job but was not able to read the parameters in the arguments. I was thinking that I can use the SDK to start the job one by one for each table in the catalog. I think it is a bug in AWS Glue and I logged a bug https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=272398&tstart=0.

I understand that AWS Glue is a wrapper on top of Spark. In spark we can read files like `s3://files-dir/my_file-*.json`. I looked but could not find a way to read data like that. Any suggestion about how to put multiple files in S3 into Redshift?

Comment: Do you actually need to load it into Redshift? If you already have the files catalogued in Glue then consider using Redshift Spectrum to expose the files as external tables in Redshift, without actually having to load the data. If you covert the files to Parquet format then performance will probably be at least as good as with actual tables in Redshift.

Comment: @Nathan Sounds good. The question is how to I change the merge the 1000 files into 1 file? I checked Glue catalog in Athana and it is showing 1000 tables. I don't want to make 1000 tables per day. As Glue is serverless spark I think it should have the capability to read all of them in. I can merge them using spark. But as Glue is meant for ETL then I should not have to start spark separately, right?

Comment: I think you just need to change your catalog settings - a "table" in the catalog can consist of many files in the same folder, you just define the path  to the data files as the folder that contains all the files. (If the files are not all in the same location then you might need to move them first). You don't need to merge multiple files into one file.